# Where do i find source code for colour histogram detection for ros hydro?

Tags: ros, object-recognition, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi can someone tell me or give me a link to where i can find colour histogram source codes? Im new to ros and im trying to use the most basic colour detection with  colour histogram to detect an object. Please help me thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191506/where-do-i-find-source-code-for-colour-histogram-detection-for-ros-hydro??/) by [Chirstina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20103/chirstina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-29**:
i am not sure if  [vosch](http://wiki.ros.org/vosch) package helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the cmvision code [wiki here](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/cmvision?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22cmvision%22)

Cheers

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chirstina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20103/chirstina/) on 2014-08-30**:
hi mark how do i download the package??